# Why is this python code not printing anything?

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, sqlite, cs50

I was trying to write a simple tiny SQL-request concole app to check if I've undestood the theme corectly. This code connects to this tiny database from IMDB: https://cdn.cs50.net/2022/fall/lectures/7/src7/imdb/

```
import sqlite3 as sql


def main():
    # try:
    #     base = Example(*argv[1:])
    #     base.search()
    # except:
    #     exit(1)
    # else:
    #     exit(0)
    base = Example(['-n', 'Keanu-Reeves'])
    base.search()


class Database:
    '''
    Can read connect to databases and send SQL requests.
    Provides output in a list of tupples.
    '''
    def __init__(self, question: list[str]) -> None:
        self._file = 'shows.db'
        self.question = question

    @property
    def file(self):
        return self._file

    @file.setter
    def file(self, value):
        self._file = value

    def output(self) -> None:
        # Connect to the database.
        connect = sql.connect(self.file)
        cursor = connect.cursor()
        # Execute query.
        return cursor.execute(' '.join(self.question)+';')

    def print_db(self):
        for i in self.output():
            for j in i:
                print(j, end=' ')
        print()


class Example(Database):
    '''
    Example child class, opens an example database, gives an output,
    formatted in nice columns.
    '''
    def output(self, request: list[dict[str]]) -> None:
        # Connect to the database.
        connect = sql.connect(self.file)
        cursor = connect.cursor(request)
        # Execute query.
        cursor.execute(request)
        # Fetch the results.
        results = cursor.fetchall()
        # Get the column names.
        columns = [description[0] for description in cursor.description]

        # Calculate the maximum length of each column.
        max_lengths = [len(column) for column in columns]
        for row in results:
            for i in range(len(row)):
                max_lengths[i] = max(max_lengths[i], len(str(row[i])))

        # Print the column names with equal distance.
        for i in range(len(columns)):
            print(columns[i].ljust(max_lengths[i]), end=' | ')
        print()

        # Print the results with equal distance.
        for row in results:
            for i in range(len(row)):
                print(str(row[i]).ljust(max_lengths[i]), end=' | ')
            print()

    def search(self) -> None:
        query: str = ''
        section: str = ''
        tables: set[str] = {}
        columns: list[str] = []

        for i in range(len(self.question)):

            match self.question[i]:
                case '-n':
                    section = 'name'
                    query = self.question[i+1].replace('-', ' ')
                case '-t':
                    section = 'title'
                    query = self.question[i+1].replace('-', ' ')
                case '-y':
                    section = 'year'
                    query = self.question[i+1].replace('-', ' ')
                case '-r':
                    section = 'rating'
                    query = self.question[i+1].replace('-', ' ')
                case '-c':
                    columns = self.question[i+1].split('-')
                    for column in columns:
                        match column:
                            case 'name':
                                tables.add('JOIN people ON'
                                           'people.id = stars.person_id')
                            case 'title':
                                tables.add('JOIN shows ON'
                                           'stars.show_id = shows.id')
                            case 'year':
                                tables.add('JOIN shows ON'
                                           'stars.show_id = shows.id')
                            case 'rating':
                                tables.add('JOIN ratings ON'
                                           'stars.show_id=ratings.show_id')
                case _:
                    columns = ['title', 'year', 'rating']

        self.output(f'SELECT {', '.join(columns)} FROM stars'
                    f'{' '.join(list(tables))}'
                    f'WHERE {section} = {query};')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I expect this code to send and receive something like this[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Orf9Z.png), but I'm getting absolutely nothing instead: no error message, nothing.

I've looked through the code and the sqlite3 python module documentation, and yet still nothing. I have no Idea why this isn't working.

Comment: This is a good opportunity to get familiar with a debugger and logging. Easiest explanation is that "results" is empty, so no loop actually happens. I'd print out the generated query first and make sure it's well constructed and actually returns results when run in isolation.

Comment: What is request in Example.output()? I see no sql query.